# jQuery: Return from click event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've written a simple function in jQuery that creates a interface that provides a textinput box and a button. When I click on the button, the function should return the value of the textbox. I know that I can't use a return command inside the click function, because it's a different scope. So my question is, how can I return the value of the textbox by clicking on the button from the function. My code looks like this :

```
function createInterface() {
    var text = $(document.createElement('textarea'))
    .css({
      width: "300px",
        height: "100px",
    })
    .appendTo($(document.body));

  var btn = $(document.createElement('button'))
    .text("click")
    .click(function() {
        // this doesn't work
        return text.val();
    })
    .appendTo($(document.body));
}
```

Thank you, have a great day.

Comment: Where do you want it to be output to? Output with an alert, or should the value be displayed in another textbox?

Comment: its working (returning the value)..but you are not mention return to where ?

Comment: where you want to return the value ?

Comment: You could create another textarea and in the onclick function makes its .val = text.val()

Comment: when i call the function by 'createInterface()' should it return the value.

Comment: But return to what? Where do you expect the value to show up ?

Comment: @rpanske at the time of  `createInterface()` call that text area is empty.that was append only at the time.

Comment: **NOT AN ANSWER BUT A QUESTION** ( was too big for comment, so I'm asking it here ) I want to know how will you get the returned value from the function ?? say you call the function like `var returned_value = createInterface();`. It won't return a value since you are returning the value on button click. So how do you want to access the returned value ?? Based on that I'll give you a solution.

Comment: @mrid I have written a other solution with callback. I knew that the function will only return a value, when the button was clicked, but I thought that there was a way to tell the function that it should wait for a click event.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really return from an event handler, you capture the valye *inside* the event handler, and do something with it.

```js
function createInterface() {
    var text = $('<textarea />', {
        css: {
            width: "300px",
            height: "100px",
        }
    }).appendTo('body');

    var btn = $('<button />', {
        text: 'click',
        click: function() {
            $('body').append( '<br>' + text.val() );
        }
    }).appendTo('body')
}

createInterface();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
function createInterface() {
var text = $(document.createElement('textarea'))
.css({
  width: "300px",
    height: "100px",
})
.appendTo($(document.body));

var btn = $(document.createElement('button'))
.text("click")
.click(function() {
    // this work
    return $(this).val();
})
.appendTo($(document.body));
}
```

--update--

sorry I make misunderstand.The Code is modified.
**Code18/4**

```
function createInterface() {
var text = $(document.createElement('textarea'))
.attr("id", "whatyouwant")
.css({
  width: "300px",
    height: "100px",
})
.appendTo($(document.body));

var btn = $(document.createElement('button'))
.text("click")
.on("click",()=> {
    // this work
    console.log($("#whatyouwant").val())
    return $("#whatyouwant").val();
})
.appendTo($(document.body));
}
createInterface();
```

Comment: that returns the value of the button not the value of the text area